# Regex for useless space in form's inputs

Tags: regex, rust, regexp-replace

I don't understand how to write a regex for these multiple patterns to be removed (with something like `.replace(pattern, "")`):

1. two or more spaces not in a string removed
2. two or more spaces in a string reduced to one (ex: " text   other " -> "text other")
3. one or more spaces removed after and before characters such as:

   1. `\n`
   2. `\r\n`
   3. `\t`
4. replace `\r\n` with `\n`

I tried with `+|\\n +|\t +\\r\n .+` but obviously this doesn't work totally.

We can use the below patterns to check it's working:

```rust
assert_eq!(not_useful_space("   "), "");
assert_eq!(not_useful_space("    a l    l   lower      "), "a l l lower");
assert_eq!(not_useful_space("    i need\n new lines\n\n many times     "), "i need\nnew lines\n\nmany times");
assert_eq!(not_useful_space("    i need  \n new lines \n\n many times     "), "i need\nnew lines\n\nmany times");
assert_eq!(not_useful_space("  i need \r\n new lines\r\nmany times   "), "i need\nnew lines\nmany times");
assert_eq!(not_useful_space("    i need \t new lines\t \t many times     "), "i need new lines many times");
assert_eq!(not_useful_space("  à   la  "), "à la");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in a single regex with `MULTILINE` flag enabled:

```bash
(?m)[ \t]*\r[ \t]*|^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$|\t]+$|([ \t]){2,}
```

Replace it with `$1` string.

[**Rust Code Demo**](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d1a1f48c5937e060710a8397c6687a3a)

**Rust Code:**

```rust
use once_cell::sync::Lazy;
use regex::Regex;

pub fn magic(input: &str) -> String {
    static REGEX: Lazy<Regex> = Lazy::new(|| {
        Regex::new(r"(?m)[ \t]*\r[ \t]*|^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$|\t]+$|([ \t]){2,}").unwrap()
    });
    
    REGEX.replace_all(input, "$1").to_string()
}

#[cfg(test)]
fn magic_data() -> std::collections::HashMap<&'static str, &'static str> {
    std::collections::HashMap::from([
        ("   ", ""),
        ("    a l    l   lower      ", "a l l lower"),
        (
            "    i need\n new lines\n\n many times     ",
            "i need\nnew lines\n\nmany times",
        ),
        (
            "    i need  \n new lines \n\n many times     ",
            "i need\nnew lines\n\nmany times",
        ),
        (
            "  i need \r\n new lines\r\nmany times   ",
            "i need\nnew lines\nmany times",
        ),
        (
            "    i need \t new lines\t \t many times     ",
            "i need new lines many times",
        ),
        ("  à   la  ", "à la"),
    ])
}

#[test]
fn test() {
    for (k, v) in magic_data() {
        assert_eq!(magic(k), v)
    }
}
```

**Javascript Demo:**

```js
function assert_eq(lhs, rhs) {
  console.log(lhs == rhs);
}

function not_useful_space(str) {
  return str.replace(/^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$|\r|([ \t]){2,}/mg, '$1');
}

assert_eq(not_useful_space("   "), "");
assert_eq(not_useful_space("    a l    l   lower      "), "a l l lower");
assert_eq(not_useful_space("    i need\n new lines\n\n many times     "), "i need\nnew lines\n\nmany times");
assert_eq(not_useful_space("    i need  \n new lines \n\n many times     "), "i need\nnew lines\n\nmany times");
assert_eq(not_useful_space("  i need \r\n new lines\r\nmany times   "), "i need\nnew lines\nmany times");
assert_eq(not_useful_space("    i need \t new lines\t \t many times     "), "i need new lines many times");
assert_eq(not_useful_space("  à   la  "), "à la");
```

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `^`: start
- `[ \t]*\r[ \t]*`: Match `\r` surrounded with optional spaces on both sides
- `[ \t]+`: match 1+ of space or tab characters
- `|`: OR
- `[ \t]+`: match 1+ of space or tab characters
- `$`: end
- `|`: OR
- `([ \t]){2,}`: match 2+ of space or tab characters
- `$1`: Is replacement to get single space/tab character back in substitution

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested, here's a non-regex version:

```
fn not_useful_space(text: &str) -> String {
    text.lines()
        .map(|line| {
            line.trim()
                .split_ascii_whitespace()
                .collect::<Vec<_>>()
                .join(" ")
        })
        .collect::<Vec<_>>()
        .join("\n")
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f41b5b918f80a9daf2a6fba44bbde86b)

Comment: Thanks a lot! What do you think about the second one here: https://users.rust-lang.org/t/how-to-remove-useless-space-in-rust-string-without-using-regex/82285/4. The one without `intersperse`. I'm benchmarking with criterion and is much faster.

Comment: Yeah quinedot's solutions are more efficient. They avoid building intermediate strings that are later discarded.